# Multiple producer One Consumer Scenario with Signaling in a Real-Time Operating System (RTOS)

Tags: multithreading, oop, synchronization, rtos, mbed

I'm developing a real-time system by making use of an mbed-OS (RTOS for ARM architecture). I'm not a software engineer and I want to know whether the following solution is practical or not, and how to improve it.

As it is shown in the figure, the elements of software are as follows:

1. Three different classes (ClassA, ...) describes low level
   peripherals for gathering data from three different modules which their instances are passed-by-reference to three different Threads (Thread a, ...).
2. By using three queues (queueA, ...), I'm sending data to the
   **Thread d** which is gathering data from the other 3 threads to combine   them to form a string in a desired format (synthesis).
3. The combined data are queued to the **Thread e** and if some
   scenarios (Happening in the first three Threads) satisfied, that data is  sent to the **Thread g**.

Now the questions are:

- Three first threads are gathering data in different update rates; How to synchronize them in the **Thread d**?
- What is the best signaling solution to aware the other threads (Event or Signal?!)
- Is the mentioned architecture practical?

Thanks.

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: I assume the label for the output of thread D is incorrect?  You have two `queueC`.

Answer (score 1):

> Three first threads are gathering data in different update rates; How to synchronize them in the Thread d?

Do they need synchronisation?  Thread d will presumably synthesise the output C based on the most recent data from all three queues.  You might simply update the current data for A/B/C as they arrive, and when either arrives generate D from current data.  If the data must be guaranteed to be "fresh" you could timestamp data arrival and only use it if all are recent enough. If you must gather fresh data from all three, you could maintain a flag for all three, set on arrival and generate D when all three flags are set simultaneously clearing the flags for the next set of data.  How you do this is really dependent on the needs of the application and your abstract description does not suggest a specific solution.

> What is the best signalling solution to aware the other threads (Event or Signal?!)

Message queues are blocking IPC, so if you wait on a single queue, arrival of data *is* signalling.  I am not familiar with Mbed RTOS specifically but most RTOS allow blocking on a single queue only.  You might combine all three queues A, B and C into one and include a data source identifier in the message - that might be simpler.  There are often good reasons however for separate queues, and to wait of data from several queues, you might use a semaphore or task event flag, that is given whenever A, B or C place data in their output queues, then D will wait of the semaphore/event and then poll all three queues with zero timeout until all three are empty before returning to wait.

You have the same issue with thread E having two input queues.

> Is the mentioned architecture practical?

Seems plausible - the abstract nature of your description does not allow to determine whether it is workable or appropriate in your specific application, but it is not insane at least.

Comment: Thanks alot for your comprehensive response. To make it more clear, consider ThreadA updates every 1 sec, ThreadB updates every 2 sec and ThreadC updates every 4 sec. ThreadD synthesizes data every 10 sec and buffers it to the next threads. I want a practical synchronization technique that assures the integrity and reliabilty of the synthesized data in ThreadD. Is there any better way to decalare queues instead of declaring before the main func?